# Javascript how to receive dates from a plain text into a formulary

Tags: javascript, html, css, linux

I need help with this code..

I need to get date in those inputs from an external plain text to fill the fields..

I have read in many forums but I have no clue how to do that... if someone of you guys could help would be helpfull!

Thanks in advance..

Here's What I have:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-panel">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Formulario </h4>
                <hr />
    <form method="post" name="ibisaserver">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Interfaz:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                       </div>      
     </div> 
      <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Direccion IP: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
       <input type="text" class="form-control"
      </div>
                    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Mascara Subred : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Direccion Gateway : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">DNS 1 : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">DNS 2 : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Direccion Broadcast : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      </div>
                    </div>
     <br><br>
     <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" name="Guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick=" this.form.action ='/ibisaserver/' " title="Guardar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>  Guardar</button>
      <button type="submit" name="Probar" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick=" this.form.action ='/probarconexion' " title="Probar Conexión"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Probar Conexión</button>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
 
</div>
```

All I need to create an external plain text and the information there should appears on those fields.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do you mean that the values are stored in a plain-text file?

Comment: Do you want to say, how to store data from these inputs in plain-text file??

Comment: @jeyoung Yes, the value are stored in a plain text file and I want to receive data from the plain text to my formulary.

Comment: @AlvaroEnrique - Please see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39757944/1342582) below how to read the file using a GET request. Then, you will have to do some JavaScript manipulation to assign the values to the fields (the markup is wrong, BTW). If you don't know how to do that, you need to start with more basic things.

Answer (score -1):

**First:** you have to load the text file using xmlHttp (if available on client system elsewhere you may use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)):

```
var mytext;
var connection = new XMLHttpRequest();
connection.open('GET', 'yourfile.txt');
connection.onreadystatechange = function() {
mytext=connection.responseText;
}
connection.send();
```

**second:** if you have wrote data in different lines, split it to an array:

```
var myarray = mytext.split("\n");
```

and finally use the array to fill the form fields.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you solution. Do you have any live example? I'm new on JS

Comment: Which part is difficult for you? using an array or loading a file? for loading a file, the above code is enough

Comment: I can not find a live example. Simply copy-pase those 7 lines of code in a script tag and put a text file naming yourfile.txt beside the file and check the result. You can add `alert(mytext)` to script  to see the result.

Comment: this is a live sample: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first